# JIRA smart commit - Block git commit without JIRA ticket number

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

I am trying to block a GIT commit if the commit message doesn't include a JIRA ticket number. Has anyone been able to do this?

From my understanding the following commit message will log the commit message on ticket `WEBSITE-4`.

```
JIRA:WEBSITE-4 #comment Testing smart commit.
```

But I need a way to block the commit from happening whenever the user forgets to include  `JIRA:<ticket number>` in the commit message.

Comment: While I don't use this in my workflows because of the overhead-per-developer, I can see how this would be ultra useful in certain critical codebases. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your own Bitbucket server, you can add a  plugin like "[Yet Another Commit Checker](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.isroot.stash.plugin.yacc/server/overview)" which does precisely that:

> Yet Another Commit Checker is a Stash plugin that allows you to reject commits to a repository based on configurable rules. Its main feature is requiring commit messages to contain a valid JIRA issue,

See its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sford/yet-another-commit-checker).

If not, as [discussed here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/148310/how-can-i-implement-a-policy-in-stash-to-prevent-check-in-without-an-issue-linked-in-the-commit), you need a pre-commit hook (client side) or a pre-receive hook (but for a public BitBucket server, that would mean a **[webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html)**) See "[Hooked on Stash](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/stash-git-hooks-api/)".

---

The "Require issue keys in commit messages" mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60451500/6309) has been introduced for [BiBucket Cloud in May 2017](https://bitbucket.org/blog/document-changes-required-issue-keys-bitbucket-cloud)

[This thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/quot-Require-issue-keys-in-commit-messages-quot-what-about-if/qaq-p/737358) adds:

> As long as you setup your links under repository settings to hook with JIRA, you do NOT HAVE TO switch on "Require issue keys in commit messages" under `Bitbucket Repository -> Settings -> Links`.
>   That is basically a rule you are setting that no one can push anything without issue keys. If you want to disable temporarily, then you can switch it off and on any time.

As [mentioned here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Require-issue-keys-in-commit-messages/qaq-p/1171253):

> **Bitbucket Server does not have the same option** to require issue keys in commit comments out-of-the-box.
>   You would have to get an app (like [Jira hooks for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211959/jira-hooks-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview) or [Better commit policy for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1214430/better-commit-policy-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview)) or write your own in order to get that functionality.
>   Or:
>
> - [Yet Another Commit Checker (a.k.a. "YACC")](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211854/yet-another-commit-checker?hosting=server&tab=overview)
> - [Control Freak](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217635/control-freak-for-bitbucket-server?hosting=server&tab=overview)

Comment: Thanks a million VonC! :)

Answer (score 1):

on the Bitbucket cloud

1. go to your Bitbucket repo -> settings -> Links
2. turn on the "Require issue keys in commit messages"